# How to use python generators with neural networks that take in data with x_train and y_train variables?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, neural-network

I have used keras' ImageDataGenerator to create labelled data by following the example in Ch 5 in Francois Chollet's book "Deep Learning with Python." As an example, I subdivided my training directory into cat and dog subdirectories, and then populated it with images. Using the following code, I created a variable that I believe contains both the image and the label.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
   train_dir,
   target_size = (150, 150)
   batch_size = 20,
   class_mode = 'binary')
```

Later on , after defining a model, you would use the following code to run the model

```
history = model.fit_generator(
   train_generator,
   steps_per_epoch = 100, 
   epochs =30,
   validation_data = validation_generator, 
   validation_step=50)
```

Many online examples of Neural Networks have separate variables that hold the test and training data (e.g. x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test). This seems the most popular method. As an example:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

And you would run the model with the following code:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=5, verbose=False, validation_split=.1)
loss, accuracy  = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=False)
```

Is there a way to convert the data created using the ImageDataGenerator into a format that would allow me to create a x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test data that's correctly formatted? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I never used Keras' ImageDataGenerators before but from the code you provided, I'm guessing you would have to create different instances of ImageDataGenerators for train, valid and test:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
   train_dir,
   target_size = (150, 150)
   batch_size = 20,
   class_mode = 'binary')
valid_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
   valid_dir,
   target_size = (150, 150)
   batch_size = 20,
   class_mode = 'binary')
```

and so on... Also, `model.fit_generator()` is deprecated.

The best workflow in my experience is to write the data generator yourself. There are a lot of examples on this, for example ([https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)). Basically, instead of returning the data by looping over the entire dataset using `return` in the function, you loop over the entire dataset by batch and `yield` the data in the function.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. I understand the need to have different instances of ImageDataGenerators for train, test, and validation. The part that I'm confused on is that ImageDataGenerators holds within it both x and y (the features and the ground truth). How do you extract that from an ImageDataGenerator instance. For example, say I've created train_generator. How do I divide it into x_train, and y_train?

Comment: Hi! Apparently, keras has a really good example: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class. Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you David, greatly appreciate the links and the help